# Magento 2 SQL query

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.3.1, and in database table, I have one column for publish date. I am sending the request parameter like 2019-08, for that i am writing the query

`$_postCollection->addFieldToFilter('publish_time', array('like' => '%'.'2019'.'-'.'08'.'%'));`

But its return empty array.

I have to achieve the query like this:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*
FROM `magefan_blog_post` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `magefan_blog_post_group` AS `group_table` ON main_table.post_id = group_table.post_id
WHERE (`main_table`.`is_active` = '1') AND (`main_table`.`publish_time` <= '2019-09-06 12:01:08') AND (group_table.group_id IN (0))
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(main_table.publish_time),"-", MONTH(main_table.publish_time))
```

i tried like this also

```
  $_postCollection->getSelect()->group(
   'CONCAT(YEAR(main_table.publish_time),"-",MONTH(main_table.publish_time))',
        'DESC'
    )->getData());
```

But in this error for getData() is coming.

Comment: In db table date save in which format?

Comment: in db table its save like "2019-07-17 12:05:00"

Answer (score 0):

try this

> ```
>     $startDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime('2019-08-01')); // start date
>     $endDate = strtotime("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2019-08-31')); // end date
>     $_postCollection->addFieldToFilter('publish_time', array('from'=>$startDate, 'to'=>$endDate));
> ```

Comment: i don't want to set start or end date.  its a dynamic value.